# Why is "null" treated as string here in the below code and is concatenated to the name of the file?

Tags: java, string, null, string-concatenation

I have a method to check the operating system type and return a suitable path according to the type of OS. This path is used by another method which accepts this path and saves a file to t
hat location. Now if the OS is not Windows, Linux or Mac then the method returns `null`. The problem is that this `null` is treated as a string and `null` gets added to the name of the saved file e.g; nullFile.txt and saves it in the location where the program is stored. 
What can I do to prevent this from happening?

```
public static String checkOS() {
    String store = "";
    String OS = System.getProperty("os.name").toLowerCase();
    if(OS.indexOf("win") >= 0){
        store = "C:/";
    } else if(OS.indexOf("nix") >= 0 || OS.indexOf("nux") >= 0 || OS.indexOf("aix") > 0 ){
        store = "/home/";
    } else  if(OS.indexOf("mac") >= 0){
        store = "/home/";
    } else{
        return null;
    }
    return store;
}
```

Comment: What do you want to happen instead? Do that.

Comment: Change return null; to `return "";`

Comment: If I return " " , then file with name File.txt gets saved still in the location where the program is. @SteelToe

Comment: What I actually want is not to save the file in any location other that than that returned by checkOS() method.  @SteelToe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't show the code, but you're probably doing

```
String filename = checkOS() + "File.txt";
```

In String concatenation, `null` values are converted to the string `"null"`, so you have to code an explicit `null` check.

```
String osName = checkOS();
String fileName;
if (osName == null)
    // do whatever you need to do
else
    filename = checkOS() + "File.txt";
```

As to the option of returning an empty string from `checkOS` instead of null, that is a possibility but in either case the caller of `checkOS` is going to need to test the result as I'm sure you want to do something different for that case.    A `null` return is the most generic option.

Comment: Good answer but why not just return a blank string in the checkos method and avoid all nulls?

Comment: That's another option, but either way the caller of `checkOS` will need to check the result because I doubt an empty string would be useful.  You wouldn't want the output file to be named just `"File.txt"`.

Comment: Ah very true. I hear.

Comment: Yes right @JimGarrison . I want to prevent the file from saving in location other than that returned by checkOS() method.